# Java - best way to add controls to a game

Tags: java, 2d, keylistener

I'm making a 2D game in Java, I used the KeyListener and some Booleans to detect key press. But the problem is, whe  I hold down a key the player wouldnt move for half a second, and then starts moving. Does anyone know how to fix this?

public void keyPressed(...)
{
PlayerX += 3;
}
Any answers would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Post relevant code / project info please.

Comment: Have you tried to separate the animations and the keyboard input code in separate threads?

Comment: @HernanVelasquez no I havent, that is not the problem though

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle controls for games in java, but my prefereble way would include a class called.. lets say "Key.class"

Inside Key.class we can have:

```
public class Key{
   // Creating the keys as simply variables
   public static Key up = new Key();
   public static Key down = new Key();
   public static Key left = new Key();
   public static Key special = new Key();

   /* toggles the keys current state*/
   public void toggle(){
       isDown =  !isDown;
   }

   public boolean isDown;
}
```

Now we have a class where we can access if certain keys are pressed, but first we need make sure that the keys .isDown function will be toggled properly. We do this in our class which implements KeyListener.

Let's say we have "Controller.class"

```
package game;
// Importing the needed packages
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Controller implements KeyListener{
//Assigning the variable keys to actual letters
public Controller(Main main){
    bind(KeyEvent.VK_W, Key.up);
    bind(KeyEvent.VK_A, Key.left);
    bind(KeyEvent.VK_S, Key.down);
    bind(KeyEvent.VK_D, Key.right);
    bind(KeyEvent.VK_SPACE, Key.special);
    mainClass = main;
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    other[e.getExtendedKeyCode()] = true;
    keyBindings.get(e.getKeyCode()).isDown = true;
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    other[e.getExtendedKeyCode()] = false;
    keyBindings.get(e.getKeyCode()).isDown = false;
}

public boolean isKeyBinded(int extendedKey){
    return keyBindings.containsKey(extendedKey);
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
}


public void bind(Integer keyCode, Key key){
    keyBindings.put(keyCode, key);
}

public void releaseAll(){
    for(Key key : keyBindings.values()){
        key.isDown = false;
    }
}

public HashMap<Integer, Key> keyBindings = new HashMap<Integer, Key>();
public static boolean other[] = new boolean[256];
```

}

Now this class will handle all of our keyBindings for us, and assuming you addKeyListener for the Canvas or whatever your game is running on it will function and change the Key.up/down/left/right/special accordingly.

Now the final step is to implement all of this into moving our character efficiently and easily.

Assuming your entities in game have update() methods which run every tick or something similar.. We can now simple add into it

```
if(Key.up.isDown) y+=3;
```

or in your case we could put it into the main class and do it the same way as long as its in the game tick loop.

```
if(Key.right.isDown) PlayerX += 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a normal behavior of the repeat (auto-repeat) for key pressed in your OS. Just try holding a key down in any text editor and you will notice that there is a short amount of time between the first character being displayed and the next ones. On Windows this is 500ms, not sure on other platforms.